# CakePHP: "Class 'HttpSocket' not found"

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to use CakePHP's HttpSocket class to make an API call, but I can't seem to get it to include the class. It seems pretty simple, so I can't see where I might be going wrong, but here's what I have:

At the top of the controller:

```
class RetailersController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array(...lots of classes..., 'HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
```

Then in the function itself:

```
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
```

And when I run that, I get:

```
Fatal Error

Error: Class 'HttpSocket' not found
```

As I said, there's not much to this, so I can't see that there's much that can go wrong - but I seem to have managed it! What can I try next?

I'm using CakePHP 2.4.

Comment: How did you get the impression $uses works this way? Please consult the official documentation. It should clearly show that you should be using App::uses() instead. PS: you can also take a look at test cases and such. They all will bring you to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this before class definition:

```
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');
```

This variable is only for models: [`$uses`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Controller.html#67-85)

Comment: Thanks! That worked (led to a new error, but still!). I hadn't picked up on that from the documentation, that $uses is only for models.

Comment: No problem, there will always be some error somewhere, we are not perfect ;)